# malloc alternative for memory allocation as a stack

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am looking for a **malloc** alternative for **c** that will only ever be used as a stack. Something more like **alloca** but not limited in space by the stack size. It is for coding a math algorithm.

- I will work with large amounts of memory (possibly hundreds of megabytes in use in the middle of the algorithm)
- memory is accessed in a stack-like order. What I mean is that the next memory to be freed is always the memory that was most recently allocated.
- would like to be able to run an a variety of systems (Windows and Unix-like)
- <s>as an extra,</s> something that can be used with threading, where the stack-like allocate and free order applies just to individual threads. (ie ideally each thread has its own "pool" for memory allocation)

My question is, is there anything like this, or is this something that would be easy to implement?

Comment: Why is standard malloc insufficient? That sounds like a use case that it would handle quite well.

Comment: I agree. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: This Goldilocks function doesn't exist in C.

Comment: I ran some tests and can see what you mean - malloc does work well. What about the threading issue? I haven't managed to test that yet.

Comment: Ok, I ran some basic threading tests, and it shows the same thing: malloc is working well. I thought earlier it was giving me issues. If I have further threading issues, I will look into some threading-friendly allocators.

Comment: From a performance standpoint, just be aware allocation is relatively costly. If you are talking about hundreds of megabytes, you wouldn't want to allocate only a few bytes at a time. It is far better to allocate a reasonable block of memory and then manage the objects in the block as needed and `free` or `realloc` the block as required.

Comment: i spoke too soon - my test was not well constructed - my test was only using a limited amount of memory at a time. After making it so that large amount of memory are in use during much of the test, malloc _is_ giving me pretty bad performance issues compared to pre-allocating a large block of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out, as long as it works with `malloc` you should use it and only come back when you need to squeeze out the last bit of performance.

An idea fit that case: You could use a list of blocks, that you allocate when needed. Using a list makes it possible to eventually swap out data in case you hit the virtual memory limit.

```
struct block {
  size_t size;
  void * memory;
  struct block * next;
};
struct stacklike {
  struct block * top;
  void * last_alloc;
};
void * allocate (struct stacklike * a, size_t s) {
  // add null check for top
  if (a->top->size - (a->next_alloc - a->top->memory) < s + sizeof(size_t)) {
    // not enough memory left in top block, allocate new one
    struct block * nb = malloc(sizeof(*nb));
    nb->next = a->top;
    a->top = nb;
    nb->memory = malloc(/* some size large enough to hold multiple data entities */);
    // also set nb size to that size
    a->next_alloc = nb->memory;
  }
  void * place = a->next_alloc;
  a->next_alloc += s;
  *((size_t *) a->next_alloc) = s; // store size to be able to free
  a->next_alloc += sizeof (size_t);
  return place;
}
```

I hope this shows the general idea, for an actual implementation there's much more to consider.

To swap out stuff you change that to a doubly linked list an keep track of the total allocated bytes. If you hit a limit, write the end to some file.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but I decided to make multithreading a part of the question. I'm not sure how that would work here other than having a different stacklike structure for each thread. The threading infastructure that I'm planning to use (intel cilk plus) handles the creation and management of threads internally.

Comment: For this you should be able to use thread local storage. I highly doubt that you'll be able to guarantee that the last allocated block will be the next freed block when multiple threads are doing the allocations. Therefore they needed to be tightly coupled, which often destroys the performance gain.

Comment: I decided to accept this answer because it seems the best based on the assumptions I gave. For multi-threading, you could create one 'stacklike' allocator for each thread. However, I've since realized the parallelism infrastructure I'm using violates the assumption I gave about threads only accessing memory in a stack-like fashion.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a perfect use for [Obstack](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Obstacks.html).

I've never used it myself since the API is really confusing, and I can't dig up an example right now. But it supports all the operations you want, and additionally supports streaming creation of the "current" object.

Edit: whipped up a quick example. The Obstack API shows signs of age, but the *principle* is sound at least.

You will probably want to look into tuning the align/block settings and likely use `obstack_next_free` and `obstack_object_size` if you do any fancy growing.

```
#include <obstack.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *rv = malloc(size);
    if (rv == NULL)
        abort();
    return rv;
}

#define obstack_chunk_alloc xmalloc
#define obstack_chunk_free free

const char *cat(struct obstack *obstack_ptr, const char *dir, const char *file)
{
    obstack_grow(obstack_ptr, dir, strlen(dir));
    obstack_1grow(obstack_ptr, '/');
    obstack_grow0(obstack_ptr, file, strlen(file));
    return obstack_finish(obstack_ptr);
}

int main()
{
    struct obstack main_stack;
    obstack_init(&main_stack);
    const char *cat1 = cat(&main_stack, "dir1", "file1");
    const char *cat2 = cat(&main_stack, "dir1", "file2");
    const char *cat3 = cat(&main_stack, "dir2", "file3");
    puts(cat1);
    puts(cat2);
    puts(cat3);
    obstack_free(&main_stack, cat2);
    // cat2 and cat3 both freed, cat1 still valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a strategy used in an old FORTRAN program that might be what you are looking for. The strategy involves use of a global array that is passed down to each function from `main`.

```
char global_buffer[SOME_LARGE_SIZE];

void foo1(char* buffer, ...);
void foo2(char* buffer, ...);
void foo3(char* buffer, ...);

int main()
{
   foo1(global_buffer, ....);
}

void foo1(char* buffer, ...)
{
   // This function needs to use SIZE1 characters of buffer.
   // It can let the functions that it calls use buffer+SIZE1

   foo2(buffer+SIZE1, ...);

   // When foo2 returns, everything from buffer+SIZE1 is assumed
   // to be free for re-use.
}

void foo2(char* buffer, ...)
{
   // This function needs to use SIZE2 characters of buffer.
   // It can let the functions that it calls use buffer+SIZE2

   foo3(buffer+SIZE2, ...);
}

void foo3(char* buffer, ...)
{
   // This function needs to use SIZE3 characters of buffer.
   // It can let the functions that it calls use buffer+SIZE3

   bar1(buffer+SIZE3, ...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not have a fixed maximum size

Comment: Also the big difficulty I'd like to avoid is having to do bookkeeping to determine how much memory each function needs. (ie don't want to have to calculate SIZE1,SIZE2, etc).